# Can rename fail if not enough file descriptors?

Tags: c, linux, rename, glibc

I noticed that during a fd leak, while the upper limit of file descriptors was reached a rename call failed. Unfortunately I don't have an error code.

Is it possible that the lack of file descriptors is related to the failing of the rename?

As far as I can see in the implementation of rename() a link() system call is used. Does it need fd's?

The implementation of rename used is from \glibc-2.17\sysdeps\posix\

Comment: What was the errno of that rename failure?

Comment: No. Rename is a system call that does not mess with your filedescriptors ; and system calls are atomic, thus, rename can fail. BTW: rename is a directory operation; the kernel needs an open inode for the directory.

Comment: It was not saved unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I compiled this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    rename("a", "a1");
}
```

and ran `strace` on the executable. Once the initialisation code is complete, all that happens is:

```
rename("a", "a1")                       = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

i.e. there are no system calls to `open` new file descriptors.

Comment: Indeed rename does not use any fd. Indirectly the problem was caused by the lack of descriptor as the file to be renamed was not created.

Answer (score 1):

The failure modes of `rename` are clearly listed on the man page:

http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/rename/

It does not mention too many open files being a problem.